# Shopware and Varnish - NS_BINDING_ABORTED during checkout/line-item/change-quantity call

Tags: varnish, shopware, shopware6

we currently have a AWS ALB -> Varnish -> Shopware configuration.
During cart item quantity update we see a NS_BINDING_ABORTED status on a /csrf/generate POST call.
Right after the checkout/line-item/change-quantity POST call succedes and the cart item quantity is updated.
We see this only on Firefox, while on Egde and Chrome the /csrf/generate POST call succedes and the checkout/line-item/change-quantity POST call is aborted, starting a /csrf/generate + checkout/line-item/change-quantity loop.

Any idea on the source of this problem?

Carlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that a double event dispatch was causing the loop.